# probability calculation

Tags: pr.probability

Given $m\cdot e$ balls, $b$ of which are black (suppose the rest are white balls). Randomly put the balls into $m$ baskets, with $e$ balls in each basket. What is the probability of the event that every basket has more white balls than black ones?

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/  This site is for upper graduate or postgrad level questions. Also, if you ask, indicate what you already know and where your problem lies so that people can help you.

Comment: Why was this off-topic? If every pattern of counts were equally likely, this would be an exercise with inclusion-exclusion, like the number of ways to get a particular total by rolling $n$ dice. However, if each way to place $e$ balls in each basket is equally likely, I don't see a simple solution.

Comment: I cannot and hence did not vote. I believe it is off-topic here because it is not research mathematics, and not because it is easy: it is not. But easy questions on advanced mathematics may be on-topic here if they come out of research. For me, it is not the difficulty that counts but the level.

Comment: Is it clear that this is not research mathematics? Why?

Comment: The problem actually comes out of some research (but not mathematical research). I have abstracted irrelevant details away from it. 

What is the definition of "research" here?

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1591/another-possible-premature-closure-probability-calculation/

Comment: Dear anonymous: I think at least some of the details that you view as irrelevant are in fact important for setting up context.  We encourage questioners to include some motivation, e.g., in the "how to ask" page linked at the top of this one.  That way, questions are less likely to be mistaken for homework or test questions.

Comment: The question has been reopened.  Please use the "edit" link below the question text to revise.

Comment: I think this is a hard problem even asymptotically for some values of the parameters. 

Answer (score 7):

let's consider a simpler question: for which values of the parameters does this probability tend to 0 or to 1?

Here are some basic estimates for the case where all the parameters tend to infinity and the ratio $r=\frac{b}{me}$ is fixed (or tends to some value). The case $r\ge \frac12$ is not interesting - clearly there will be some black majorities with high probability. If $r<\frac12$, then the probability of a black majority in a given basket is roughly
$$r^{e/2}(1-r)^{e/2} {e \choose e/2} \approx \frac{\big(2\sqrt{r(1-r)}\big)^e}{\sqrt{e}}$$
where the approximation is up to a multiplicative constant. For this approximation to hold we need to assume that $m$ grows quickly enough for the difference between sampling with and without replacement to be negligible. This is certainly the case when $m$ grows exponentially, which is the relevant regime.

In that regime we also have that the results for different baskets are asymptotically pairwise independent, hence we can get an upper and lower using union bound and the second moment method and conclude that when
$$m\ll  \frac{\sqrt{e}}{\big(2\sqrt{r(1-r)}\big)^e}$$
the probability of a black majority in some cells tends to 0, and when
$$m\gg  \frac{\sqrt{e}}{\big(2\sqrt{r(1-r)}\big)^e}$$
the probability tends to 1.

Comment: Why "the case $r\le 1/2$ is not interesting"?

Comment: On quick inspection it seems this is 'flipped' from what it should say. But clearly half the range of r is not interesting (as one simply has not enough of the relevant balls to achieve a majority  in each basket). And this does not seem to affect the substance of the answer much (or at all).

Answer (score 3):

Since the first bin contains $k$ balls with probability
$$\frac{{e\choose k}{me-e\choose b-k}}{{me\choose b}},$$
we get the recursion relation
$$p_e(m,b)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor e/2\rfloor}\frac{{e\choose k}{me-e\choose b-k}}{{me\choose b}}p_e(m-1,b-k)$$
with $p_e(m,b)$ denoting the probability that each of the $m$ bins filled with $e$ balls contains at least as many
white than black balls where the total number of black balls is $b$ and with the bins 
filled randomly in an obvious sense. (If we want strict inequality,
we have to replace the upper summation-bound $\lfloor e/2\rfloor$ by
$\lfloor (e-1)/2\rfloor$.

Using the obvious initial condition $p_e(1,b)=1$ if $b\leq e/2$ (respectively 
$b$ strictly smaller than $e/2$ if we wish strict inequality) and $p_e(1,b)=0$ otherwise,
we can compute $p_e(m,b)$ by an algorithm needing roughly the computation of $2mb+m$
binomial coefficients
and having a memory requirement $b$ (by computing $p_e(a+1,0),\dots,p_e(a+1,b)$
using the values $p_e(a,0),\dots,p_e(a,b)$.

Comment: This recursion is more efficient than the one I used.

Comment: Why did you ignore the part
$\sum_{k=\lfloor (e-1)/2\rfloor}^{\min(b,e)}\frac{{e \choose k}{me-e \choose b-k}}{{me \choose b}}$?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a real answer.

You can find some probabilities using a clever loop when the partition(m*e) is not huge, where I am using partition() to mean the integer partition function from number theory.  This is still not as clever as a hypothetical closed form answer.  I assume that the answer isn't just a binomial coefficient or something, otherwise someone would have already answered it.

Here are some naive calculations for m=3, e=3, followed by less naive, but not closed-form, calculations for m=10, e=10.

```
m: 3
e: 3

b: 0
nways naive: 362880
nways_fast : 362880
prob: 1

b: 1
nways naive: 362880
nways_fast : 362880
prob: 1

b: 2
nways naive: 272160
nways_fast : 272160
prob: 3 / 4

b: 3
nways naive: 116640
nways_fast : 116640
prob: 9 / 28

b: 4
nways naive: 0
nways_fast : 0
prob: 0
```

Calculations for m=10, e=10:

```
m: 10
e: 10

b: 0
prob: 1

b: 1
prob: 1

b: 2
prob: 1

b: 3
prob: 1

b: 4
prob: 1

b: 5
prob: 29875 / 29876

b: 6
prob: 567535 / 567644

b: 7
prob: 63785 / 63826

b: 8
prob: 37531985 / 37593514

b: 9
prob: 45347875 / 45507938

b: 10
prob: 6463929125 / 6507635134

b: 11
prob: 1586911975 / 1605780098

b: 12
prob: 981182104025 / 1000401001054

b: 13
prob: 384868375 / 396669707

b: 14
prob: 1066668675750 / 1115831885791

b: 15
prob: 989247906939375 / 1055576963958286

b: 16
prob: 1489819534516125 / 1631346217026442

b: 17
prob: 19844564270625 / 22459084339538

b: 18
prob: 964555447190625 / 1137829714396594

b: 19
prob: 155522927593125 / 193114800728458

b: 20
prob: 143007636792729375 / 189059389913160382

b: 21
prob: 24103622043759375 / 34374434529665524

b: 22
prob: 75602536926778125 / 118068709906242452

b: 23
prob: 220551587574103125 / 383723307195287969

b: 24
prob: 14932881008409375 / 29517177476560613

b: 25
prob: 4988973826968750000 / 11456881600545026503

b: 26
prob: 4360116559500000 / 11932476001162801

b: 27
prob: 6180351555497625000 / 20750575766022110939

b: 28
prob: 205959103466801625000 / 876984860006092372843

b: 29
prob: 251666129503125000 / 1411735350344467939

b: 30
prob: 5283557104214784375000 / 40794916418904090033283

b: 31
prob: 10699432321455000000 / 119633185979190879863

b: 32
prob: 618306212430000000 / 10623796438306526011

b: 33
prob: 235960695639900000000 / 6682367959694804860919

b: 34
prob: 518835697776900000000 / 26336391370561877981269

b: 35
prob: 2874702717526500000000 / 289700305076180657793959

b: 36
prob: 1506044508147900000000 / 342373087817304413756497

b: 37
prob: 15293171450812500000 / 9253326697764984155581

b: 38
prob: 241217215312500000 / 487017194619209692399

b: 39
prob: 1350816405750000000 / 12774835643473115777543

b: 40
prob: 9455714840250000000 / 779264974251860062430123

b: 41
prob: 0
```

I was mildly annoyed to not find anything in oeis.  Maybe I am bad at searching oeis, or maybe I am doing the math wrong.