# Approximate closed-form solution for a recurrence

Tags: recurrences, co.combinatorics, na.numerical-analysis

Find an (approximate) closed-form solution for $S(m, b)$.

$$S(m,b)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor (e-1)/2\rfloor}{e \choose i}S(m-1, b-i) \quad + 
    \sum_{i=\lfloor (e-1)/2\rfloor+1}^{\min(b,e)}{e\choose i}{(m-1)e\choose
    b-i}$$

Comment: Needs some motivation or reason anyone should care about it.  Perhaps some interpretation involving a random walk or ??.

Comment: Is this maybe some type of Eulerian numbers?

Comment: @Gerald, there might be a connection with the OP's other question, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130115/probability-calculation -- but if so, it would be nice to make it more explicit.